# Scheme: "mcar: contract violation, expected: mpair, given: #<procedure:..."

Tags: lambda, stream, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to use streams to generate a list of prime numbers in Scheme and I am encountering an error that I can't seem to wrap my head around.  I have been spending hours trying different things and feel like I somewhat understand the problem, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.  I have looked at similar posts, but I don't think I'm experienced enough to be able to relate them to my problem.

```
(define int-builder$
    (lambda (n)
      (cons  n (lambda() (int-builder$ (+ n 1))))))

(define filter-out-mults$
    (lambda (num lst)
          (if (= (modulo (car lst) num) 0)
              (filter-out-mults$ num (cdr lst))
              (cons (car lst) (lambda () (filter-out-mults$ num (cdr lst)))))))
(define take$
    (lambda (m s)
      (if (or (= m 0) (null? s))
          '()
          (cons (car s) (take$ (- m 1) ((cdr s)))))))
```

int-builder$ generates an infinite stream of integers starting at n.  filter-out-mults$ should filter out any non-prime numbers.  take$ takes the first m primes from the list.

Here is how I am running it, along with the error message:

```
> (take$ 10 (filter-out-mults$ 2 (int-builder$ 2)))


mcar: contract violation
expected: mpair?
given: #<procedure:.../prime-stream.ss:10:8>
```

I believe the problem has to do with how filter-out-mults$ is called in the if/else statement, in that a new int/procedure pair is not passed in, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(cons  n (lambda() (int-builder$ (+ n 1))))` and then `(filter-out-mults$ num (cdr lst))` => KABOOM! (you probably want `list` instead of `cons` there)

Comment: I figured it out.  As I mentioned in my edit, I needed an extra set of parentheses around (cdr lst) in order to invoke it.  The lambda prior to (filter-out-mults$ num ((cdr lst))) actually makes the procedure lazy so that it doesn't go forever.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you use [SRFI-41 Streams library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-41.html)?

Comment: You should post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with the [SRFI-41 Streams library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-41/srfi-41.html). It's available in many implementations including Racket. Racket also has [it's own stream library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html) with many similar procedures/syntax. SRFI-41 is available from both #!Racket and #!R6RS.

```
;(import (rnrs) (srfi :41)) ; For #!R6RS language
(require srfi/41)          ; For #!Racket language

(define-stream (filter-out-multipliers n v stream)
  (let ((a (stream-car stream)))
    (cond ((< a n) (stream-cons a (filter-out-multipliers n v (stream-cdr stream))))
          (else (filter-out-multipliers (+ n v) v (if (= a n) (stream-cdr stream) stream))))))

(define-stream (primes stream)
  (let ((a (stream-car stream)))
    (stream-cons a (primes (filter-out-multipliers (+ a a) a (stream-cdr stream))))))

(stream->list (stream-take 20 (primes (stream-from 2))))
; ==> (2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71)
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to answer my own question shortly after posting and wanted to share my solution.

In filter-out-mults$, each

```
(cdr lst)
```

needed to be

```
((cdr lst))
```

Since int-builder$ is a stream, it returns pairs containing an integer and a procedure to get the next integer token.  For example:

```
> (int-builder$ 2)
(2 . #<procedure:...prime-stream.rkt:10:8>)
```

In order to get the next integer, the procedure needs to be invoked.  The problem was that (cdr lst) would return the procedure, but not invoke it.  To illustrate:

```
> (cdr (int-builder$ 2))
#<procedure:...prime-stream.rkt:10:8>
```

Once the extra parentheses were added, the next pair was returned:

```
> ((cdr (int-builder$ 2)))
(3 . #<procedure:...hedgerh.lab6.rkt:10:8>)
```

Hopefully that helps someone.

Here is the full definition of filter-out-mults$:

```
(define filter-out-mults$
    (lambda (num lst)
      (if (null? lst)
          '()
          (if (= (modulo (car lst) num) 0)
              (filter-out-mults$ num ((cdr lst)))
              (cons (car lst) (lambda () (filter-out-mults$ num ((cdr lst)))))))))
```